# load file from MS-DOS batch file

Tags: batch-file, dos

recently I've been into making games in MS-DOS batch script. I have worked out how to create a file for saving but I can't seem to find out how to load this data. I know how to do this in modern windows 7 batch files:

`:load
    < NAME.FILETYPE (
    set /p VARIABLE=
    set /p VARIABLE=
    set /p VARIABLE=
::and so on
)`

But since actual MS-DOS (I'm using v6.22 if that changes anything) doesn't have /p so that isn't possible. So, my question is, is there any way to do this without using /p?

Comment: Your choices are to use `Qbasic` that will set the variables by reading the file and writing a temporary batch file, or by piping the data through `date` or `time` commands and parsing the output into a temp bat file.  Choose your weapon. :)  FWIW Qbasic is more robust and simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Create the save file with .bat extension this way:

```
(
echo set var1=%var1%
echo set var2=%var2%
echo set var3=%var3%
) > SETVARS.BAT
```

Then recover the values of variables this way:

```
call SETVARS
```

**EDIT**: *Response to the comments and downvote*

I think there is a confussion here. The OP said in the question that "I have worked out how to create a file for saving". My answer *should be understood as*: "use your method to create the saving file, but with .bat extension and this contents:"

```
set var1=value of var1
set var2=value of var2
set var3=value of var3
```

Then load the data with a `call theFile.bat` command. I am pretty sure that this method works in any MS-DOS version that allows to `call` an external Batch file...

**EDIT #2**:

You may use this method to create the save file:

```
echo set var1=%var1%> SETVARS.BAT
echo set var2=%var2%>> SETVARS.BAT
echo set var3=%var3%>> SETVARS.BAT
```

Comment: Which part? The `( block )` redirection? It may be replaced by the original method the OP uses to create its original file...

Comment: Thanks! the loading file works! now for some reason it doesn't like the `(
echo set var1=%var1%
echo set var2=%var2%
echo set var3=%var3%
) > SETVARS.BAT` bit. It keeps saying "bad command or file name" when it gets to the brackets (I removed the @echo off bit to what was happening)

Comment: here's the code that I am using to test the program:

Comment: IGNORE PREVIOUS COMMENT    here's a link to download the program that I am using to test the code and an image of what has gone wrong: [link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/8yszia3pi18gynz/save_-_load_program.zip) (it's easier to do this than to give you the code directly)

Comment: Yes, the `( echo ... ) > SETVARS.BAT` don't work in MS-DOS. See the Edit #2 in my answer.

Comment: If this answer was useful to you in order to solve your problem, may I ask you to select it as Best Answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It works now! previously the brackets were mucking things up but I now make a save file using:

```
':save
    del setvars.bat
    echo set var1=%var1% >> setvars.bat
    echo set var2= %var2% >> setvars.bat
    cls
    echo saved!
    pause >nul
    goto main'
```

and load using:

```
':load
    call setvars.bat
    cls
    echo loaded!
    pause >nul
    goto main'
```

thanks everyone!
p.s. the fact that I have to indent this code so I can submit an answer is stupid. Batch isn't usually indented at all!